# remove all occurence of words in string if found in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings and a dynamically generated variable `x`. What I want to do is remove all occurrences in variable `x` if they are found in the array. Check below to better understand my question.

**NOTE:** The array is expected to contain a lot of elements so the more efficient the code the better. Also, there might be multiple occurrences of words and they all must be removed if found in `myArr`

```js
//expected to contain a lot of elements
myArr = ["test", "green", "blah", "foo", "bar"]

//dynamic variable
x = "this is my test string with color green"

//dumb approch 
x = x.replaceAll("test", "").replaceAll("green", "").replaceAll("blah", "").replaceAll("foo", "").replaceAll("bar", "")

//expected result is the x string with the words inside myArr removed
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```js
// Array containing the words to remove
const myArr = ["test", "green", "blah", "foo", "bar"];

// Dynamic variable
let x = "this is my test string with color green";

// Create a regular expression that matches any word in myArr, including optional spaces around the word
const regexPattern = myArr.map(word => `\\s*${word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}\\s*`).join('|');
const regex = new RegExp(`(${regexPattern})`, 'gi');

// Replace all occurrences of the words in x, including surrounding spaces
x = x.replace(regex, ' ').trim();

// Replace multiple spaces with a single space
x = x.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

// Log the result
console.log(x);
```

Code explanation:

- The `map` function is used to escape any special regex characters in the words.
- `\\b` in the regex ensures that only whole words are matched (avoids partial matches).
- The `gi` flags make the regex global (affects all occurrences) and case-insensitive.
- The `replace` method then replaces all occurrences of the matched words with an empty string.

### Edit

If your array elements contain brackets and parenthesis you need to include parenthesis and brackets in the escaping logic. Additionally `'\\b'` word boundary might not work as expected so you might need to use a different approach to prevent partial matches.

```js
// Array containing the words to remove
const myArr = ["(test)", "green", "blah", "foo", "bar"];

// Dynamic variable
let x = "this is my (test) string with color green";

// Function to escape special characters
const escapeRegExp = (word) => word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

// Create a regular expression that matches any word in myArr
const regexPattern = myArr.map(escapeRegExp).join('|');
const regex = new RegExp(`(?:^|\\s)(${regexPattern})(?:$|\\s)`, 'gi');

// Replace all occurrences of the words in x
x = x.replace(regex, ' ').trim();

// Log the result
console.log(x);
```

### Edit 2

Another way to solve your problem is to split your string into words and filter out the words that are  in your array.

```js
// Split the string into words
let words = x.split(/\s+/);

// Filter out words that are in myArr
words = words.filter(word => !myArr.includes(word));

// Join the words back into a string
x = words.join(' ');
```

this is also way easier to read and understand.

Comment: hey, this won't work when the array element contains brackets and parenthesis. Eg. ```myArr = ["(test)"] wont be removed from string

Comment: @seriously I edited my code

Comment: this is what I need thanks for the help!

Comment: @seriously I added a version that is way easier to understand

Comment: performance wise which one would u recommend?

Comment: @seriously if your input string is very large a well designed regex pattern would perform better.

Comment: There is a bit of an issue with your regex. You are not taking into account the space that is added once you replace a matching word. Impressive though.

Comment: @seriously I modified my regex to avoid partial matching

Comment: @AliMustafa you're  right I added a `trim()`

Comment: nice explanation!

Comment: Trim won't do anything here.  Trim only works if there are trailing or leading spaces. The spaces you have are in between the words when one word is replaced. Like between `is my  string` you have two spaces between my and string because a word was replaced. Triming the word has no effect here.

Comment: @AliMustafa what approach would u recommend to avoid partial matching without introducing extra spacing inside ```myArr```

Comment: Add a space character in regex (at the end preferably) but I wonder it will add complexity as you will have to handle some corner cases.

Comment: @noah1400 whats ur new edit?

Comment: @AliMustafa you are right `trim()` wouldn't work. I was confused. I edited my regex. This makes it way more complex though and not really neccassary because it doesn't solve the issue anyway ( because of parenthesis and brackets )

Comment: It is regex bro. It is supposed to be complex. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. I don't know what efficient means in the context. I am using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to iterate over the string and remove each element one by one.

```js
//expected to contain a lot of elements
myArr = ["test", "green", "blah", "foo", "bar"]

//dynamic variable
x = "this is my test string with color green"

//dumb approch 
myArr.every((y)=>{
  x = x.replaceAll(y+' ', '');
})
console.log(x)
```